# Teamcity build implicit requirement with agent enviroments

Tags: teamcity, cicd, teamcity-8.0

I set up the agent, set the JAVA environment variables necessary for it to work and build my projects.
In teamcity, these variables are pulled up.

pic - https://ibb.co/Qc6Ctd7

But some build steps need to be done with a specific version of java.
According to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/agent-requirements.html#Implicit+Requirements), I specify the required variable for the Java Parameters > JDK home path field in build steps of my configuration.

pic - https://ibb.co/wCqzk7z

The most interesting thing is that it highlights the possible option for specifying a variable..

But when it comes to settings that are compatible to run the build, the agent
I get a notification that the agent on **which the JDK_17 variable is registered**, and **which was highlighted to me in the JDK home path field**, is incompatible due to:
*Implicit requirements:
env.JDK_17 defined in Build step: Maven build*

pic - https://ibb.co/Gsg9BFH

Perhaps there is some problem in teamcity itself in conjunction with agents on unix?

I uses TeamCity Professional 8.0.2 on 2008 windows server and Ubuntu 22.10 as agent machine

I ask for help, since I myself have already climbed all possible forums and articles, I did not find anything like this...